# iOS build view programatically depending on object ivar

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uilabel

I have a pretty funny problem which involves `loadView`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`and the state of an ivar. I have a navigation based app. And from my first level view I have a table list and then I click on one of the cells it will take me to second level view (detail view). When I click on a cell I also add an "`Office`" object (which contains strings like `streetAddress`and `boxAddress`) to the view controller that gets pushed. I then populate the detailed view with the contents from the `Office` object like `[box setText:[self.office boxAddress]];` (box is a UILabel). Now what I want to achieve here is that sometimes the stringValue of boxAddress is empty and in those cases I don't want to add an empty string to the UILabel, instead I want to move the next UILabel up (and take the place of the boxAddress). So therefore I've made a conditional check to see if `boxAddress` is empty if it is it should set up `UILabel`s with specific coordinates and if it's not empty it should set up `UILabel`s with other specific coordinates.

I understand that you should use `viewWillAppear` if you want the code to be run everytime the view is loaded. But for some reason it seems that `viewWillAppear` is only ran when the `boxAddress` string is noy empty. And if I click on a cell that has an empty `boxAddress` it will use the value from `boxAddress`from the last cell that I clicked that had a non-empty `boxAddress`.

I'll paste my code here to see if you can give me a pointer on what I'm doing wrong here.

```
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, 
// without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {

    //allocate the view
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

    //set the view's background color
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    //add the labels
    name = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,10.0,320.0,20.0)];
    [name setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [name setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    street = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,30.0,320.0,20.0)];
    [street setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [street setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    //if no box address, move up the rest of the addresses
    if ([[self.office boxAddress] length] == 0) {

        zip = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,50.0,320.0,20.0)];
        [zip setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [zip setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        phone = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,70.0,320.0,20.0)];
        [phone setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [phone setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        fax = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,90.0,320.0,20.0)];
        [fax setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [fax setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        [self.view addSubview:name];
        [self.view addSubview:street];
        [self.view addSubview:zip];
        [self.view addSubview:phone];
        [self.view addSubview:fax];

    } else {

        box = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,50.0,320.0,20.0)];
        [box setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [box setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        zip = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,70.0,320.0,20.0)];
        [zip setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [zip setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        phone = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,90.0,320.0,20.0)];
        [phone setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [phone setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        fax = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0,110.0,320.0,20.0)];
        [fax setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [fax setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

        [self.view addSubview:name];
        [self.view addSubview:street];
        [self.view addSubview:box];
        [self.view addSubview:zip];
        [self.view addSubview:phone];
        [self.view addSubview:fax];
    }

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

// viewWillAppear method is run every time the view is loaded as opposite to the viewDidLoad method which only is run once
// in this program DisclosureDetail view needs to be loaded for each detail view with different content each time
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    NSLog(@"%@", [self.office boxAddress]);

    [name setText:[self.office name]];
    [street setText:[self.office streetAddress]];
    if ([[self.office boxAddress] length] > 0) {
        [box setText:[self.office boxAddress]];
    }
    [zip setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [self.office zipCode], [self.office city]]];
    [phone setText:[self.office phoneNo]];
    [fax setText:[self.office faxNo]];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ([[self.office boxAddress] length] > 0) {
    [box setText:[self.office boxAddress]];
}
```

If `boxAddress`'s length is 0 then `box` will continue to contain whatever text you set in it the last time the view appeared.

You're going to need to hide and show `box` every time the view appears not just when the view is loaded because the view might be loaded and then used to display multiple different `office`s.

Comment: But I thought the viewWillAppear method is ran every time the view is showed hence then if `boxAddress` is empty it shouldn't show? How would I go about hiding and showing `box`? If I hide it will the UILabels under it be placed "over" it so to speak?

Comment: `viewWillAppear` is called when you expect but nothing resets your view's content for you so if you don't update `box` it will continue to display whatever it contained the last time the view appeared. If you hide `box` nothing will happen to the other labels, you would need to reposition them yourself. A common solution for this sort of interface is to make each field a cell in a table view so that you can adjust which cells appear and they will stack vertically.

Comment: So the easiest solution would be to use a tableview? What would some pseudo-code look for the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ? Would it be using a switch on `row` and then displaying different data depending on rows?